# Autowiring :expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot, autowired

Okay, I know that there are many questions asked around the same topic. But I cant seem to make anything work. It also might be the case that I am yet to completely understand the auto wiring concept.
My Problem: 
I am able to get to the required page, but whenever I click on the any button to perform an action I get Null pointer exception which seems obvious as I dont think spring is able to properly map the bean needed.

So, when I add @autowired=true , it gives me the above given exceptionn.
I am not sure what needs to be done.. Hope someone can help me out with this. Would love an explanation as well:)
Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userDetails")
public class UserDetailModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int user_id;
public String password;
public String user_name;
public String active_status;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getActive_status() {
    return active_status;
}

public void setActive_status(String active_status) {
    this.active_status = active_status;
}
```

}

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserDetailController {

 private Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailController.class);
 @Autowired(required = true)
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestBody UserDetailModel user) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    logger.debug("in controller");
    UserDetailModel userDtl = new UserDetailModel();
    userDtl.setUser_id(user.user_id);
    userDtl.setUser_name(user.user_name);
    userDtl.setActive_status(user.active_status);
    userDtl.setPassword(user.password);

    userRepository.save(userDtl);
    return "Saved";
}
```

}

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserDetailModel,         Long> {}
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.springBoot.usl.repo.UserRepository com.springBoot.usl.controller.UserDetailController.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.springBoot.usl.repo.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:683)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:944)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:933)
at com.springBoot.usl.controller.WebAppInitializer.main(WebAppInitializer.java:18)
```

**Solved based on the responses**
**Answer:**
I made some modifications based on Jay and Luay's answers. And changed the annotations as follows in my ApplicationConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.basepackage.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"my.basepackage.*"})
@EntityScan("my.basepackage.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

Hope this helps some one.

But I am not sure if * is the right way to go.

Answer (score 10):

I am able to run your application with some changes on annotation side.

I have used same classes which are given in question. Please see below structure and configuration used.
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9g2Y.jpg)

I have used packages as below and added your classes,
 **com.rcmutha.usl.controller** 
 **com.rcmutha.usl.repository**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.rcmutha*"})
@EntityScan("com.rcmutha*")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.rcmutha*")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

For complete code : 
[click here for code](https://github.com/Roshanmutha/JPARepo_44149690)

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Great.Please provide up vote if it worked for you so that developers can try correct solutions.

Comment: I was using 3 different layers for dao, service, controller(springboot) but for me it was not finding service bean i used these annotations main application class it worked. Thanks

Comment: My problem was in `@ComponentScan("x.y.z.controller")`. Changed to `@ComponentScan("x.y.z.*")`

Answer (score 2):

I think your application is not able to scan the `UserRepository` class, If you are using Spring Boot then you should put the main class on top of your package hierarchy.

You should also use `@EnableJpaRepositories` and tell it the base package of your repos to enable the repository functionality

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={"com.springBoot.usl.repo"})`

Comment: Thanks. But when I add this, I get Error creating bean with name 'userDetailController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExcept‌​ion: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Comment: If you are following Jay's answer you should not get this error because you will be creating bean `entityManagerFactory` in that example, However, if you are using Spring Data JPA with Spring Boot you will not need to create a bean of entityManagerFactory spring will provide one to you

Answer (score 1):

`UserRepository` is simply not defined in the current Spring Context. 
Make sure that your class is defined in a package that is scanned by Spring. You will need to use `@ComponentScan("org.my.pkg")` in your Configuration class to make Spring scan the package.

If you're using Spring Boot, make sure you locate your main application class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` in a root package above other classes, as it contains `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the JPA repositories in your config class, specify the package that contains the repositories as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.springBoot.usl.repo"
})
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

Example of ApplicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.springBoot.usl.repo"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx");
        dataSource.setUsername("xxxx");
        dataSource.setPassword("xxxx");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I add this, I get
 Error creating bean with name 'userDetailController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Answer (score 0):

I know that the problem was solved, but as it can be problem for someone else like I had, I decided to share my problem and the solution. 
I got exactly the same error message, but the problem was the **lack of the annotation @Service in a class** and hence an object of this type couldn't autowire. After putting this annotation, everything worked fine.

Below is the object of the mentioned class:

```
@Autowired
private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
```

Just this annotation caused the same problem and can pass unnoticed:

```
@Service  // annotation that was missing
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in a kotlin + spring boot application and could solve it thanks to this solution slightly modified:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("package.path*")
```